# Apache on Debian : server flooded by a lot of 400 , how to protect from it?

Tags: apache-2.4, ddos, syn

My HTTPS server has been experiencing slowness for a few days, so I consulted the log file (the access.log, I use apache2). And I found out that my server is flooded by a lots of 400 :

[image]

If I change the apache config for stop listening the port 443, the flood of queries stop (but my website becomes inaccessible x) )

I tried to add some iptables rules. I try theses rules by example :

```
/sbin/iptables -N SYN_FLOOD
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -j SYN_FLOOD
/sbin/iptables -A SYN_FLOOD -m limit --limit 10/s --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
/sbin/iptables -A SYN_FLOOD -j DROP
```

([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654005))

When I add the last rule (`-A SYN_FLOOD -j DROP`), the flood stopped (great !) but my website become again inaccessible :/

My knowledges about server administration and the iptable command are very limited... why my website become inaccessible after this rules ? what should I modify ? maybe the use of iptable its not a good approach for my issue ?

Thank for any help/explanation :)

EDIT (after petitradisgris answer):

I installed and config fail2ban this night. I add theses jails :

```
> cat /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

# detect password authentication failures
[apache]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-auth
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 3
findtime = 600
bantime = 86400

# detect potential search for exploits and php vulnerabilities
[apache-noscript]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-noscript
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 3
findtime = 600
bantime = 86400

# detect Apache overflow attempts
[apache-overflows]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-overflows
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2
findtime = 600
bantime = 86400

# detect failures to find a home directory on a server
[apache-nohome]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-nohome
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 2
findtime = 600
bantime = 86400

[apache-fakegooglebot]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
maxretry = 1
ignorecommand = %(ignorecommands_dir)s/apache-fakegooglebot <ip>

[apache-badbots]
# Ban hosts which agent identifies spammer robots crawling the web
# for email addresses. The mail outputs are buffered.
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
logpath  = %(apache_access_log)s
bantime  = 48h
maxretry = 1

##To stop DOS attack from remote host.
[http-get-dos] 
enabled = true 
port = http,https 
filter = http-get-dos 
logpath = /var/log/apache*/access.log 
maxretry = 400 
findtime = 400 
bantime = 200 
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]

[iptables-dropped]

enabled = true
filter = iptables-dropped
banaction = iptables-allports
port = all
logpath = /var/log/messages
bantime = 1800
maxretry = 3
```

The config of my jails seems ok :

```
> sudo fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:  9
`- Jail list:   apache, apache-badbots, apache-fakegooglebot, apache-nohome, apache-noscript, apache-overflows, http-get-dos, iptables-dropped, sshd
```

This morning, fail2ban ban IPs but only in `sshd` jail (strange...) :

```
> sudo cat /var/log/fail2ban.log* | grep Ban

2022-06-13 07:07:59,185 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 23.94.194.115
2022-06-13 07:08:32,529 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.156.122.114
2022-06-13 07:09:10,601 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 182.156.209.222
2022-06-13 07:09:18,831 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 186.10.125.209
2022-06-13 07:09:30,867 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 139.59.21.115
2022-06-13 07:11:15,736 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 213.136.90.174
2022-06-13 07:11:45,799 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 154.194.12.69
2022-06-13 07:14:50,174 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.156.124.5
2022-06-13 07:18:09,188 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 118.27.106.123
2022-06-13 07:18:55,509 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 104.248.89.194
2022-06-13 07:19:05,742 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 23.94.194.115
2022-06-13 07:19:11,811 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.154.104.24
2022-06-13 07:19:45,166 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 178.35.169.154
2022-06-13 07:20:36,453 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 139.59.21.115
2022-06-13 07:20:55,694 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.156.122.114
2022-06-13 07:21:33,806 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 186.10.125.209
2022-06-13 07:22:10,109 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 27.74.254.115
2022-06-13 07:22:56,385 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 213.136.90.174
2022-06-13 07:24:10,698 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 154.194.12.69
2022-06-13 07:25:34,062 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 104.248.62.102
2022-06-13 07:26:21,350 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.154.171.84
2022-06-13 07:29:57,842 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 118.27.106.123
2022-06-13 07:31:46,106 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 139.59.21.115
2022-06-13 07:33:49,576 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 27.74.254.115
2022-06-13 07:33:50,797 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 186.10.125.209
2022-06-13 07:34:22,899 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 213.136.90.174
2022-06-13 07:37:13,410 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 104.248.62.102
2022-06-13 07:38:07,498 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.154.171.84
2022-06-13 07:38:16,138 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 177.229.215.234
2022-06-13 07:40:44,582 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 104.248.89.194
2022-06-13 07:45:30,321 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 27.74.254.115
2022-06-13 07:46:31,019 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 186.10.125.209
2022-06-13 07:48:59,939 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 104.248.62.102
2022-06-13 07:49:51,227 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.154.171.84
2022-06-13 07:50:01,263 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 177.229.215.234
2022-06-13 07:50:59,390 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 46.19.137.50
2022-06-13 07:57:09,964 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 27.74.254.115
2022-06-13 08:01:50,508 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.154.171.84
2022-06-13 08:02:04,542 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 177.229.215.234
2022-06-13 08:02:39,206 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 104.248.89.194
2022-06-13 08:14:18,245 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.129.209.91
2022-06-13 08:16:07,008 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 167.99.158.168
2022-06-13 08:16:50,289 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.128.101.73
2022-06-13 08:24:37,536 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 104.248.89.194
2022-06-13 08:25:21,615 fail2ban.actions        [529]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 43.129.209.91
```

And the flood is always here...

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/site1_access.log /var/log/apache2/site2_access.log /var/log/apache2/site2_access.log

...
180.190.87.231 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
111.71.212.176 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
39.112.83.149 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
115.186.169.59 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
61.15.198.157 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
183.222.197.241 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
114.45.171.90 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
61.62.148.146 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
1.173.221.202 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
27.82.146.136 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
27.109.247.56 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
180.177.24.124 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
116.49.174.155 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
61.231.235.55 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
14.192.212.91 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
219.91.104.20 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
60.49.40.31 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
60.49.40.31 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
171.97.223.126 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:15 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
61.38.43.211 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
120.231.123.126 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
221.184.60.12 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
113.43.210.22 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
180.190.87.231 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
115.43.157.151 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
122.100.135.240 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
117.183.115.211 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
223.86.195.24 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
122.100.145.152 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
112.120.167.195 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
36.229.143.45 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
110.26.97.247 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
121.171.109.192 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
113.254.111.51 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
112.104.89.188 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
14.192.212.91 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
36.238.159.112 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
219.91.104.20 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
198.16.63.120 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
115.87.13.52 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
61.231.235.55 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
121.6.78.165 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
121.109.135.202 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
183.227.201.149 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
61.38.43.211 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
112.120.167.195 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
180.94.189.179 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
59.149.254.6 - - [13/Jun/2022:08:30:16 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 0 "-" "-"
...
```

I discover 'fail2ban', maybe there is a missing or mistake in ma config of jails ?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the 'fail2ban' software in your linux system: [Tutorial in this link](https://linuxhandbook.com/fail2ban-basic/)

The default confiiguration should help.

If not, you may easily write some specific rules that smartly block those traffic (banning IPs doing to much specific requests like that).

EDIT: here is an example of a jail that may fit your problem:

```
[ban-400]
logpath = /var/log/f2b-400.log
filter =
port = 80,443
failregex = ^<ADDR> \S+ \S+(?: \[\])? "[^"]*" 400\s
enabled = true
```

However:

1. the actual requests that gives a 400 error appears valid to me, so in my understanding, they should return a 200.
2. Thoses IP may comes from web scrapper (web browsers) and others things like that...So you don't want to ban an IP aiming at referencing you on a web browser...right?

So you should consider resolving this error 400 issue, where your apache2 should report a 200 status code. Did you disabled http1.0 in your config?

EDIT: regarding your iptable SYN_FLOOD.

The problem with it, is that a SYN request is part of a legitimate communication.

Moreover, as you are in TCP, a SYN request (and probably SYN/ACK) is sent many times to server until having response.

So, the server will count many SYN request per host (per second) and the iptables rules will block them...

Comment: Hi and thanks you for you help ! I edit my initial post :)

Comment: Updated my post too.

Comment: http1.0 is not disable on ma apache config , may I disable it ? because when I go to my websites, the version used by HTTP is 1.1 (I see that in my access.log file). But if I disable all http v1.0 request, maybe I'll refuse legitimates queries ? (facebook bot, google bog, ...)

Comment: When a client make a request in http1.0, your server will answer in http1.1 but in compatibility mode(so everything is fine). If you disable http1 0 for clients, this would lead to the error 400 answers totally similar of what you have. Don't disable it ;)